# Why my mobile sends SMS to a random number without my permission?

Tags: one-time-password, sms

My mobile sends SMS to random numbers without my permission. All messages are sent automatically. Here is an example of an SMS.

> SBIUPI qUrXgeX26iEY%2B2si9JHhubIjm7R2aHoo6pWcbXBpJho%3D

All the receivers are Indian numbers (mostly airtel sim card). When I check the Truecaller app I found those numbers are named Cybercrime Frauds and reported as spam by more than 18000 peoples.

I have checked my app SMS permissions and checked for hidden apps. I couldn't find anything harmful.

Is there anything to afraid?

Comment: Do you know for sure that these messages are actually being sent from your phone - as opposed to being sent from some other device and spoofed to make it look like they were sent from your number?

Comment: I am not sure that those messages are sent from the phone. But my message app shows that I have sent. I am using stock android mobile and google messages.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have "SBI UPI" The State Bank of India (SBI) Unified Payments Interface (UPI) app on the phone which is sending your payment card info via SMS.

Answer (score 2):

I also had been afraid of this and complained. It's just a verification message from your side. If you are using paytm, every time you verify your phone number it'll send a key (like the one you mentioned) from your phone to paytm, for verifying. I am not sure why people reported those numbers as spam. But I think it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: if you have a reference for *paytm* software sending confirmation codes via sms it would finish this answer off nicely